# how to convert a .mts into a .mov in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, converters, mov, .mov

I was wondering if there is any way or any code to convert a .mts into a .mov with xcode. I need this code for my mac app to work correctly. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do this inside xcode.  If you just want to convert mts files to mov files, you could use a utility like this one:

http://www.mtsconverter.com/convert-mts-to-mov.html

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear, but if you want the application to do this for the user, your mac app you should bundle in a compiled copy of [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).

Otherwise, just use `ffmpeg` yourself from the command line or from one of the many gui clients.